# Product Images Problem after saved in All Store View Scope from Admin Panel

Tags: magento2, product-images

Magento 2.4.6-p1 recently upgraded from 2.4.5

Updating any product image is not reflected on the front end, However when I change the scope from `All store view` to `Default store` view and update images.
Changes are reflected immediately on the front end.

I am using only the default website with the default store view.

Changed `Single-Store Mode` from No to Yes but the same issue exists, now reverted back to NO.

Comment: The issue reported on magento as others are also facing issue of scope of media gallery with backend and frontend scope.
Check if this help you https://github.com/magento/community-features/issues/23

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/210166)

Answer (score 0):

This is a Magento core bug/issue and it's not yet fixed on the latest version at present, i.e. Magento 2.4.6.

#### Steps to reproduce the issue

**Duplication of image attributes on store view complicates gallery management**

1. Admin create a product (global scope)
2. Admin add images to product and set one as an image, small image and thumbnail (global scope)
3. Admin switch to some store view and edit any field not related to gallery (store view scope)
4. Admin save product. At this moment attributes for all images are copied from default (admin) store view to edited store view
5. Admin switch back to global scope
6. Admin can not properly manage gallery from global scope

   - Admin edit image attributes but they are not reflected on store front as store view already has own copy of attributes
   - Admin try to delete image with special role but system shows error message (edited scope has own information about image role so blocks image deletion)

**Required fixes (in order of severity)**

1. Provide possibility to use default value for Media Gallery Entry attributes (should be enabled by default).
2. Always persist new media gallery entry in default (admin) store view.
3. Add scope labels to UI for media gallery entries.

**Issue Reported here:**

- https://github.com/magento/community-features/issues/23
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10863

The issue is not fixed yet, i.e. the feature/fix listed above is not implemented yet.

- I can reproduce the issue on Magento 2.4.5-p4.
- One of the comments in the above issue link says the issue is also reproducible on Magento 2.4.6